# Rust pattern for container object

Tags: rust

I have a struct which owns various other structs, e.g.

```rs
pub struct Computer {
  monitor: Monitor,
  keyboard: Keyboard,
  mouse: Mouse,
  printer: Printer
}
```

some of these child objects require each other, which leads to build errors like "Cannot borrow as mutable more than once at a time".

```rs
self.mouse.change_orientation(&mut self.keyboard);

impl Mouse {
  fn change_orientation(&mut self, keyboard: &mut Keyboard) {  
    // ignore the fact that the example does not make much sense,
    // for some reason this method really needs to mutate both the mouse
    // and the keyboard
  }
}
```

I can imagine this is a common problem / pattern if you come from a more OOP background. There's a container object that owns smaller objects that perform different tasks. When one of these small objects needs a reference to another, the reference is tied to the container object as far as Rust is concerned.

How would you refactor this code so that it works with Rust? I'm a bit hesitant going full on with `Rc<RefCell` everything because I do like the benefits of the compile time borrow checker.

Edit: apologies, I have made a mistake. As pointed out in the comment, the example I provided actually works. My bad. What I was trying to do in my actual code was to pass the entire container as a mutable reference, which of course shouldn't work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with rust 1.50. Can you show us a reproducible example?

Comment: Your code [works for me](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=36ed5b6eb6f65eb5ef01687a578be712) so you will have to give us a [mre] (emphasis on _reproducible_) to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Often, these things can be solved via borrow splitting: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/borrow-splitting.html

I.e. you explicitly make the compiler understand that you are mutating two separate entities.

Comment: This is very promising, I was not aware of it. I will study it in the afternoon. Thank you!